# Counting rows with different conditions in one query

Tags: postgresql, count

Let's say I have this table:

```
 id | status | type
----+--------+----------
  1 | new    | car
  2 | new    | boat
  3 | used   | car
  4 | new    | car
```

and I wanted to count all the `new` vehicles, and the number of `cars` in one go, how to do that?

I tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT(status='new'), COUNT(type='car') FROM table;
```

but it always counts to 4 (the total amount of rows). The only thing I can think of is using a `CASE` inside the `COUNT`, but is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `FILTER` to perform conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE status='new'), COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE type='car')
FROM tab;
```

Alternatively `SUM`:

```
SELECT SUM((status='new')::int), SUM((type='car')::int) FROM table;
```